# Why sort is slower than order function in R?

Tags: r, sorting, microbenchmark

All is in the title. I would expect that `order` uses `sort` to find the order of the values in a vector. Thus `sort` should be quicker than `order` to sort a vector, but this is not the case:

```
library(microbenchmark)
ss=sample(100,10000,replace=T)
microbenchmark(sort(ss))
microbenchmark(ss[order(ss)])
```

result:

```
> microbenchmark(sort(ss))
Unit: microseconds
    expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 sort(ss) 141.535 144.6415 173.6581 146.358 150.2295 2531.762   100
> microbenchmark(ss[order(ss)])
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
 ss[order(ss)] 109.198 110.9865 115.6275 111.901 115.3655 197.204   100
```

Example with a larger vector:

```
ss=sample(100,1e8,replace=T)
microbenchmark(sort(ss), ss[order(ss)], times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
#           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#       sort(ss) 5.427966 5.431971 5.892629 6.049515 6.207060 6.346633     5
#  ss[order(ss)] 3.381253 3.500134 3.562048 3.518079 3.625778 3.784997     5
```

Comment: note that your timings are on the order of microseconds. please set the size of the sample to at least 1 million (preferably 10 million or 100 million) and update the timings

Comment: @MichaelChirico both of these functions use (the same) O(n) algorithm for integer vectors, so you're not going to see much more separation with larger inputs.

Comment: Thank @Ryan for the update with larger example. Is clear then than `sort` keep being aroun 1.6 times slower that `order`. But as suggested by @Dan Hall in his answer, this ratio shrink to 1.15 when using directly `sort.int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The treatment of `NA` values under the default arguments is different. In `sort`, the entire vector must be scanned for `NA` values, which are then removed; in `order`, they are simply put last. When the argument `sort.last = TRUE` is used in both, the performance is basically identical.

```
ss=sample(100,1e8,replace=T) 
bench::mark(sort(ss), ss[order(ss)], sort(ss, na.last = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression    min   mean median    max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result
  <chr>      <bch:> <bch:> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 sort(ss)   2.610s 2.610s 2.610s 2.610s     0.383 762.940MB     0     1     2.610s <int ~
2 ss[order(~ 1.597s 1.597s 1.597s 1.597s     0.626 762.940MB     0     1     1.597s <int ~
3 sort(ss, ~ 1.592s 1.592s 1.592s 1.592s     0.628 762.940MB     0     1     1.592s <int ~
# ... with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer and should have the green checkmark. If I could take it away from mine and give it to you I would. Thanks for coming back to this a year later.

Comment: I just saw the answer and changed the accepted answer. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 5):

because `sort.default()` uses `order` (rather than the other way around).

```
function (x, decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA, ...) 
{
  if (is.object(x)) 
    x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]
  else sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, 
    ...)
}
```

`sort` has to determine its method, then execute the same `x[order(x)]` call you're executing in one step when you use `x[order(x)]` directly.  You can ramp up the size of the input as much as you want. For an integer vector, `x[order(x)]` should always outperform `sort(x)`.

[@Hugh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527444/7936744) a year later demonstrates that the bulk of the difference is in the default treatment of `NA` values. It should be the accepted answer here.

Comment: just want to be clear I wasn't saying the timing would flip, just that it would not look "strikingly" different once the timings see actually meaningful.

Comment: This certainly proves that sort won’t be generally faster than order but it seems incomplete. Determining the method and executing is.object should only take microseconds and shouldn’t be too dependent on the length of x.

Comment: @Hugh class determination and method selection end up being a significant part of the computational cost throughout R. One of the first steps to take when improving efficiency in R is to select a method directly.

Comment: I don't deny it's significant, but it's the minority of the difference: `sort` **2.7s**, `sort.int`: **2.6s**, `x[order(x)]`: **1.5s**. Something else is going on.